# STL map - no matching constructor

Tags: c++11, dictionary

I have a std map that combines a string with a function pointer like:

```
 std::map<std::string, void (*)()> funcs {
       {"print", &h::print},
       {"scan", &h::scan_cmd},
       {"connect", &h::stream},
       {"stream", &h::stream}
 };
```

where h is the enclosing class in which this map has been initialized:

```
class h {
public:
   void print();
   void scan();
   void connect();
   void stream();
   std::map<std::string, void (*)()> funcs {
           {"print", &h::print},
           {"scan", &h::scan_cmd},
           {"connect", &h::stream},
           {"stream", &h::stream}
     };
};
```

I get this error:

```
No matching constructor for initialization of 'std::map<std::string, void (*)()>' (aka 'map<basic_string<char>, void (*)()>')
```

I've also tried puttting the map in this form:

```
std::map<std::string, void (*)()> funcs;
funcs["print"] = &print;
funcs["scan"] = &scan_cmd;
funcs["connect"] = &stream;
funcs["stream"] = &stream;
```

But then I got this error:

```
Size of array has non-integer type ' const char [6]'
```

I'm not exactly sure where the problem is - my guess is that it's with the void (*) () portion. I'm sure this is a c++ 11 compiler.

Comment: Are you sure you have a C++11 compiler? Also, your code is broken around "connect" (mismatched quotation marks?).

Comment: And please show the definition of `h` and of its type.

Comment: @KerrekSB I've updated it - thanks!

Comment: (`void connect(); void stream();…"connect", &h::stream},` looks funny as does `funcs["connect"] = &stream;`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void (*)()
```

is pointer to ordinary function which takes no arguments and returns no value.
In your example `print`, `stream`, `scan_cmd` are non-static member functions of `h` class. Syntax to define pointer to member functions of `h` class looks like

```
void (h::*)()
```

Try:

```
   std::map<std::string, void (h::*)()> funcs {
           {"print", &h::print},
           {"connect", &h::stream},
           {"stream", &h::stream}
     };
```